# Nested includes resulted in object keys names cutted off

Tags: sequelize.js

When I query a model with M:N relation and nest some more includes inside - I have object-keys names cutted off to fixed length.

UserGroup has a M:N relation to BitrixResponsible as 'bitrix_responsible'
There is a model named BitrixPortal with a column named 'webhook_inbound_url'

With a model-query params like this:

```
{
  include: [
    {model: models.BitrixResponsible.scope('with_relations_deep'), as: 'bitrix_responsible'}
  ]
}
```

and configured scope

```
BitrixAccount.addScope('with_relations', {
  include: [
    { model: BitrixPortal.scope('self_only'), as: 'bitrix_portal'},
  ],
})
BitrixResponsible.addScope('with_relations_deep', {
  include: [
    { model: BitrixAccount.scope('with_relations'), as: 'bitrix_account'},
    { model: UserPosition, as: 'position'},
  ],
})
```

and BitrixPortal model

```
class BitrixPortal extends Model {}
BitrixPortal.init(
  {
    id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true },
    account_id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, allowNull: false },
    default_responsible_id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, allowNull: true },
    // other fields
    webhook_inbound_url: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
    webhook_outbound_token: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
    // other fields
  },
  {
    ...default_model_options(
      'bitrix_portals',
      'bitrix',
      'BitrixPortal',
      true, true),
    defaultScope: {
      attributes: {
        exclude: ['webhook_inbound_url', 'webhook_outbound_token']
      },
      include: [],
    },
    scopes: {
      ...default_model_scopes(),
    },
  }
)
```

I query one record of UserGroup, and instead of some value by path
`record -> bitrix_responsible -> [0] -> bitrix_account -> bitrix_portal -> webhook_inbound_url`
I got a record with key 'webhook_inboun'
`data.bitrix_responsible[0].bitrix_account.bitrix_portal.webhook_inboun`
There are other keys with long names in the resulted nested BitrixPortal record, those names cutted off too.
Example of query response

```
{
  "created_by": "023b123d-f535-4b8b-9964-e60f12279ea6",
  "updated_by": "023b123d-f535-4b8b-9964-e60f12279ea6",
  "deleted_by": null,
  "created_at": "2023-09-27T08:22:12.394Z",
  "updated_at": "2023-09-28T03:22:12.787Z",
  "deleted_at": null,
  "hierarchyLevel": 2,
  "parentId": "11625860-5095-433a-a1b8-72862bf10430",
  "users": [...],
  "managers": [...],
  "access_assigns": [...],
  "telegram_auth_requests": [...],
  "ticket_responsibles": [],
  "bitrix_responsibles": [
    {
      "bitrix_account": {
        "bitrix_portal": {
          "base_url": null,
          "data": {},
          "id": "a402473f-4286-4431-8ce8-c72d345a6071",
          "account_id": "ceb07684-9abe-43c0-a262-5923d4427d9a",
          "default_respon": "cc8e44b1-0578-4e17-8a9f-738d52a9b132",               // <- HERE
          "b24_user_id": "1061",
          "b24_group_id": null,
          "b24_crm_prefix": "T95",
          "b24_crm_id": null,
          "webhook_inboun": "https://domain.bitrix24.ru/rest/1265/token_asdasd/", // <- HERE
          "webhook_outbou": null,                                                 // <- HERE
          "is_active": true,
          "created_by": "023b123d-f535-4b8b-9964-e60f12279ea6",
          "updated_by": "71ea0ad5-cee5-4629-afa9-247d04412907",
          "deleted_by": null,
          "created_at": "2023-09-27T05:04:17.347Z",
          "updated_at": "2023-09-27T09:46:39.899Z",
          "deleted_at": null
        }
      },
      "position": {
        "id": "48a6bc8a-f84b-4501-963e-ff366868d9b1",
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

Replacing scope with the same includes gave me the same result, so it's not "scope"-related issue.

For now I query BitrixResponsible without nested includes.

```
{
  include: [
    {model: models.BitrixResponsible.scope('self_only'), as: 'bitrix_responsible'}
  ]
}
```

Collect IDs of record.bitrix_responsible and query for BitrixResponsible with scope `'with_relations_deep'` and `where: { id: record.bitrix_responsible.map(r => r.id) }`
And it works fine, no key-names cutted.

Versions:

- Node: v18.17.1
- sequelize: "^6.33.0"
- sequelize-hierarchy-fork: "^1.0.0"

**So my question is:** is this a bug or am i missing some sequelize option/version update to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Do you use PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, dockerized postgres 15.2

Comment: then look at `minifyAliases` option of Sequelize instance

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL by default has 64 characters limit for column names and aliases so you should use `minifyAliases` option of Sequelize instance:

> A flag that defines if aliases should be minified (mostly useful to avoid Postgres alias character limit of 64)